# My othercards contents(buttons) are hiding when I press button from the card

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing attendance list for employee. To list that employee, I used `recyclerView` and `cardView`. The `cardview` contains is not showing some buttons. I'm using `FirebaseRecyleAdapter` in java class. When I press the first employee card of button from that currently 11 one card button is hidden. How to solve this issue?

```
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
```

Comment: Share your `FirebaseRecyleAdapter` class here

Comment: I was trying to fix the grammar in your question, but I can't understand what you mean by "When I press the first employee card of button from that currently 11 one card button is hidden.". Can you explain a little more?